# How can I mirror Gmail settings on another Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

I've spent a lot of time making my Gmail experience 'just so' for my personal account, and now my office has moved to Google Apps (I moved us). How can I copy all of my awesome settings, labs, gadgets etc. from my labs email to my new Gmail account?

Comment: Not all labs are available for Google Apps.

Answer (score 1):

There is just no way to do that so far. The closest thing to getting there would be the [Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/), made by google employees. But sadly there's [nothing there for your needs](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail) - just importing mails and contacts.